# PHP save and load class to binary file

Tags: php, class, binary

What is the best way to convert class to binary data and back? Can not convert it back from binary to class.
For example:

```
class myclass{
public $a=50, $b=100;   // 1 byte size
public $c=5, $d=1;      // 2 bytes size
function test(){
    $data = pack("c2s2", ...array_values((array)$this)); //ok
    $this = unpack("c2s2", $data); // not working!!!
}}
```

Unpacking to separate array then assigning each field separately is not the best way for me. Maybe  there is another way? I will handle thousands of such objects with much more fields and want to store them in maximally compact binary form.

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but _Cannot re-assign $this_

Comment: Just `unserialize` and let the things happen. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

Comment: On  Quasimodo's clone link found list() function. Now it looks like list(,$this->a,...) = unpack("c2s2", $data). As i know serialization stores field names not needed in my case.